# What is the type of the relationship in the class diagram if the object is initiated or referenced in a method?

Tags: c#, uml, class-diagram

I am doing a reverse engineering to one system and creating a class diagram.

The code is similar to this example:

```
class B
{
}

class C
{
}    

class A
{
    C GetC()
    {
       return new C();
    }

    void Foo()
    {
       B b = new B;
       C c = GetC(); // this function returns a reference to an object of type C
    }
}
```

I want to know if I have this code what is the relation between the class A and B, A and C?

Comment: Are you talking about UML diagram? It's a dependency, "use": class A _uses_ B and C.

Comment: We could say that this is a sort of composition, though B and C are not declared as properties.

Comment: Yes I am talking about UML Diagram, I think the relation between A and C is a dependency "use", but I am not sure if it is an aggregation between A and B

Comment: @FouadKayali OK then it's a _dependency_. See answer for few more details and references.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming it's UML class diagram then you have a *dependency*. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) (emphasis is mine):

> [Dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_(UML)) is a weaker form of bond which indicates that one class depends on another because it uses it at some point in time. **One class depends on another if the independent class is a parameter variable or local variable of a method** of the dependent class. This is different from an association, where an attribute of the dependent class is an instance of the independent class.Sometimes the relationship between two classes is very weak. They are not implemented with member variables at all. Rather they might be implemented as member function arguments.

For example:

[image: UML example]

In your case class `A` *uses* class `B` and class `C`. It's a dependency and it's not [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) because of highlighted text: `b` and `c` are (at least in that example) local variables then association between `A` and them is merely their usage (not even a weak [aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation)).

OK, to be honest - I hope UML purists won't blame me too much - I would say *use* instead of *composition* because (guessing from code fictionally example) `b` is a *tool* to complete `Foo()` task. If it was used (even if local variable) to make (from an external point of view) `A` a *container* for `B` then I'd say composition. For example in this case:

```
class RocketLauncher {
    public void Launch(World world, Location target) {
        AutonomousObject rocket = world.Rocket.Factory.Build(_structure);
        rocket.MoveTo(world, target);
    }

    private static LauncherStructure _structure;
}
```

Even if strictly speaking `Rocket` is *used by* `RocketLauncher` I'd tend to define both (`LauncherStructure` and `Rocket`) as *composition*. From an outside point of view a `RocketLauncher` is composed by (is made of, has) a structure and a rocket (even if current implementation delegates creation to last moment). Point (IMO) is what you want to represent with this diagram. If you're describing implementation then *point of view* doesn't matter: dependency is dependency and composition is composition.

If you're describing higher level architecture you would keep implementation details out of the diagram and try to describe class *interface* (of course when implementation greatly differs from abstract architecture there may be smell of something wrong - in implementation or in architecture - and **reasons** - if any - **must be documented**).

Comment: But the class B is initiated in the method Foo(), that means the object b is owned by the class A

Comment: See highlighted text: it's not composition because b is a **local variable**.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming **GetC()** is only ever used in **Foo()** the relationship of A to B and C is *exactly the same*.

This is because you could refactor the code to look like this :

```
void Foo()
{
   B b = new B;
   C c = new C;
}
```

This relationship is a weak relationship as it is exactly written in your example. I would classify it as a **depends** relationship.

If you were to have them as class variables like this :

```
B b;
C c;
void Foo()
{
   b = new B;
   c = new C;
}
```

you would possibly be looking at **aggregation**. If Foo() were to be called inside a constructor then you would be looking at **composition** (ie. **b** and **c** live and die with the object)

Comment: This is exactly my take on the issue as well.  +1 for a very clear explanation.

Comment: The second example you provide is a composition relationship, not aggregation because the class manages the dependencies life cycle!